# What does Leveling up skills do?

Tags: disgaea-3, disgaea-4

In Disgaea 3 and 4 you can spend Mana to power up skills and with Spells this also adds more tiles to the spell range's and it's Area of Effect. while i can't say anything for normal skills i know in previous Disgaea games however leveling up your spells added more tiles to the spell range's and it's Area of Effect.

So what does Leveling up a skill do in Disgaea 3 and 4?

NOTE: i am away that a skill needs to be leveled up at least once to keep it during reincarnation but i'm talking about subsequent levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It increases the damage or healing these the spells do, by [1% per level in Disgaea 3](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/942139-disgaea-3-absence-of-justice/answers/230340-what-good-does-skill-level-do) and [3% per level in Disgaea 4](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995078-disgaea-4-a-promise-unforgotten/60382064). If the spell has no direct damage or healing effect (eg. boost spells) then apparently levelling up the spell has no effect.